# Font is corrupt seemingly everywhere

Tags: fonts

When I download DIN Regular from a variety of websites, this is what it looks like in Mac OS font previewer...

[image]

What is wrong with this font?

Comment: When you say ‘a variety of web sites’ does that mean that you are getting this for free? This is not a free font, so if you didn’t pay for it then what you have are almost certainly illegal copies. If they don’t work then it’s just a case of you get what you (didn’t) pay for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of web sites which seem to have for ex.10000 fonts freely downloadable.

If you check one of those sites, because you have found they have the wanted font, you sometimes can read something like this:

*This font is not ours, it belong to some other, if you download it, you must obey copyright owner's terms of usage. We do not take any responsibility of the consequenses, if you download or use it.*

People have uploaded for various reasons the content of those sites. In addition those sites can find content from each other. Long time ago when MP3 music files came available, commercial music came freely available as pirate versions in the same way.

So, there's surely plenty of fonts which can be found from tens of download sites. They can be cracked if they originally had some copy protection system, they can contain malware, they can be modified or corrupted by some errors, nobody takes responsibility.

At least distributing malware is very plausible reason to make commercial fonts freely available. It's well possible that you have just met it in practice. It's as well possible that there's nothing that pollutes Mac, it takes only Windows. Or the file only contains some badly implemented "humorous" glyphs which are made and uploaded by some technically non-competent no-taste humorist.

There are also plenty of established reliable font distributors. They do not give commercial fonts for free. They have clearly defined way to communicate with them. They can have also free fonts, but even they have clearly defined licenses. Use their services if you want to avoid the difficulties that can come with pirated stuff.

Letters that you can find in DIN font, have been published as German standard in 1931 to rationalize documentation in German industry and official affairs. It's not a single typeface, but a whole family, some for printing and some for manual lettering. Search for DIN 1451 for details.

Despite it was a standard, the implementations of it can well be commercial products. For example nobody gives lettering rulers for free. Commonly used DIN 1451 Mittelschrift and Engschrift typefaces are available as computer fonts from several commercial font suppliers such as Monotype or Linotype.

There's some free computer font implementations of DIN 1451 typefaces. Check, if you can use D-DIN from FontSquirrel in terms of the license, technical quality and how tightly it follows the standard.

D-DIN is free. If you can pay, check FF-DIN. It came famous due its excellent onscreen clarity in small sizes.

Comment: Yes, its available here... https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-din/